# Keyboard scroll up and hide Toolbar and Status bar on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to keep status bar and toolbar still visible on top while displaying soft keyboard. I tried many ways but cannot done. Tried windowSoftInputMode and set/clear flag of windows, but all failed. 
Could anyone help me, please ? 
[Please click here to see gif file!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dAXG.gif)

Comment: Could you please post your layout and activity codes? And what values have set for `windowSoftInputMode`?

Answer (score 5):

This is a Xamarin bug. See [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39765).

There are some workaronds. You have to do the following in your MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    //Remove the status bar underlay in API 21+
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
    {
        Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = 0;
        var statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        statusBarHeightInfo.SetValue(this, 0);
        Window.SetStatusBarColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(18, 52, 86, 255));
    }


    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());

    App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
}
```

If you use FormsApplicationActivity instead of FormsAppCompatActivity, then you have to remove the following lines:

```
var statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
statusBarHeightInfo.SetValue(this, 0);
```

You can see more details with Jimmy Garrido [here](https://gist.github.com/jimmgarrido/e36033b26f01e8da091fd321d41d991a).

But to hide ActionBar, **if you use the following code** in your MainActivity, so only the **above solution will not work**:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never);
```

**To fix the problem**, what worked for me was to delete this line above and create a specific theme to make the ActionBar disappear.

Under Resources / values / Styles.xml I created a new theme (you can change yours if you already have one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">0dp</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And don't forget to change your theme in MainActivity, like:

```
[Activity(WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan, Label = "Test", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme",  MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

I hope this can help you.